# Fix DRY code help javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was making a basic jquery slider but i noticed that i repeated myself twice basically. The only difference is the var prev and prev method. And the first method to last method.

```
 left.on('click', function(){
  var current = $('.active');
  var prev = current.prev();
   if (prev.length === 0){
    prev = $(".slides").last();
   }

   current.fadeOut(300).removeClass("active");
    prev.fadeIn(300).addClass("active");
 });

right.on('click', function(){
 var current = $('.active');
 var next = current.next();
 if (next.length === 0){
   next = $(".slides").first();
 }
 current.fadeOut(300).removeClass("active");
 next.fadeIn(300).addClass('active');
});
```

I have tried this function but it doesn't work. I'm a beginner so I don't know if this type of function is even possible.

```
function slider(x, y){
 var current = $('.active');
 var x = current.x();
 if (x.length === 0){
   x = $(".slides").y();
 }
 current.fadeOut(300).removeClass("active");
 x.fadeIn(300).addClass('active');
}); 
right.on('click', slider("next", "first"));
left.on('click', slider("prev", "last"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `right.on('click', slider("next", "first"))` to

```
right.on('click', function(){
  slider("next", "first");
});
```

See if that works.

Comment: Alternatively: `function slider(x,y) { return function() {...}}`

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to access some dynamic values in your function. when you do that you have to use the bracket notation `[]`. That said `current.x` and `$(".slides").y()` will not work. what you can do is acccess them with brackets like this `current[x]` and `$(".slides")[y]()`

```
function slider(x, y){
 var current = $('.active');
 var slides = current[x]();
 if (slides.length === 0){
   x = $(".slides")[y]();
 }
 current.fadeOut(300).removeClass("active");
 slides.fadeIn(300).addClass('active');
});
```

Also your event handling is wrong on click you are registering a function call which will produce an error. you can either create a closure for the call or pre-bind the functions

Closure

```
right.on('click', () => slider("next", "first"));
left.on('click', () => slider("prev", "last"));
```

Binding

```
right.on('click', slider.bind(null, "next", "first"));
left.on('click', slider.bind(null, "prev", "last"));
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! That was basically my other question that how do I change methods like .prev and .next dynamically. I combined your bracket notation and Hans event handler. But why does using brackets add that "dot" ?

Comment: @Zach4531 there are two ways of accessing object properties. the dot notation access the name of the value to the right. doing current.x it will look for a property named `x` on object `current`. with the brackets notation it will evaluate the variable passed so it convers it to a string and then access the property with that name

Comment: That makes more sense thanks for the answer. My code is much easier for me to read now. Shaved off many lines of code.